# As fun as it sounds, it's actually very toxic

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I was talking about gossiping and said *"As fun as it sounds, it's actually very toxic."* I wanted to mean that 'even though gossiping sounds fun, it's very toxic.'

I think I've heard people say this kind of sentence this way, but I'm not sure if my sentence was correct. Could anyone please help me use this phrase correctly?

A few examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You got 3 answers on Reddit already, that seemed pretty good.

Comment: Yes I actually did but I was looking for a few example sentences since I couldn't find any anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine. Personally, I would drop the first *as*

> Fun as it sounds, ...

because the common pattern seems to be

> <adjective> + **though** + <noun>/<pronoun> + <verb>

or

> <adjective> + **as** + <noun>/<pronoun> + <verb>

and the verb is usually a linking one (such as appear/become/be/seem/look/feel/sound/become)

You have other options to express contrast:

> Even though it sounds fun, ...

> Although it may sound fun, ...

> However fun it may sound, ...

> No matter how fun it sounds, ...

Comment: Around here (Northern England), "As fun as it sounds" would be the normal and colloquial way of saying it, with "fun as it sounds" appearing only if somebody's speaking particularly fast or carelessly and skipping lots of words.  Regional difference, maybe.  Apart from that, everything you said sounds right and I don't know why the downvote.